# Google Sheet - Data separation in Rows

Tags: worksheet-function, worksheet

I have a Google sheet like this with sample data with about 100 Rows.
Some rows have only one line data
Some rows have Column B & C with two line data and Column D & E with one line data
Some rows have Column B & C with one line data and Column D & E with two line data
Some rows have Column B & C and Column D & E with two line data

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
State       Date       Type       Date       Game      Remarks

NY        02/15/24    Type A    03/15/24    Game AA     No

NJ        02/25/24    Type B    03/20/24    Game BB     No
02/27/24    Type C

CT        03/10/24    Type D    04/15/24    Game AE     No
04/20/24    Game CA

TX        04/10/24    Type G    05/20/24    Game XA     No
04/15/24    Type H    05/24/24    Game TX     Yes

What the best way to use either function or script to separate two line data so I can create a dashboard per Date from Column B and Date from Column D?

Could not find any solution from online forum or videos.

[Attached screenshot of table for better view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gBQj.png)